# Объединение строк в SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется таблица:

```
|тип|время_начала|время_конца|понедельник|вторник|среда и тд
| 2 |9:30        |10:30      |True       |False  |True
| 2 |11:30       |12:30      |False      |False  |True
```

На выходе нужно объединить строки по типу, и вместо True подставить время, должно получится что-то вроде:

```
|тип|понедельник  |вторник|среда
| 2 |9:30 - 10:30 |       |9:30 - 10:30, 11:30 - 12:30
```

Таблица, понятное дело, утрирована, но думаю, понятно, в чем суть. Подскажите, куда копать, с чем разбираться, чтобы составить такой запрос. Запрос очень сложный, но если кто-то сможет написать, буду признателен. В общем буду рад любой помощи.

Для написания запросов использую обычный SQLServer.

Comment: Это обязательно делать на sql? Можно же запросить данные как есть, а к нужному виду преобразовать на языке типа php, c#, etc.

Comment: ну я на C# пишу и там столько гемора, что проще будет в sql

Comment: Для начала для каждого дня недели написать что то вроде `case when [понедельник]=True then concat([время-начала], '-', [время_конца] end` получите строки где вместо true/false будет время. потом это надо будет сгруппировать и использовать для сборки строк при группировке xml path или string_agg в зависимости от версии sql-server, http://www.cyberforum.ru/sql-server/thread160915.html https://database.guide/the-sql-server-equivalent-to-group_concat/

Comment: @ВадимМороз С вашей структурой БД на SQL будет гемора не меньше, чем во внешнем языке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В комментариях было выяснено, что автор использует C#, поэтому осмелюсь предложить решение на этом языке.

Входные данные:

```cs
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("тип", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("время_начала", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("время_конца", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("понедельник", typeof(bool));
dt.Columns.Add("вторник", typeof(bool));
dt.Columns.Add("среда", typeof(bool));

dt.Rows.Add(1, "9:30", "10:30", true, false, true);
dt.Rows.Add(1, "8:30", "14:30", true, true, false);
dt.Rows.Add(1, "7:30", "13:30", true, true, false);
dt.Rows.Add(2, "9:30", "10:30", true, false, true);
dt.Rows.Add(2, "11:30", "12:30", false, false, true);
```

Я использовал `DataTable`, но это может быть типизированный список.

```cs
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row["тип"])
    .Select(g => new
    {
        тип = g.Key,
        понедельник = JoinGroup("понедельник", g),
        вторник = JoinGroup("вторник", g),
        среда = JoinGroup("среда", g)
    })
    .ToList();

foreach (var a in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.тип + " | " + a.понедельник + " | " + a.вторник + " | " + a.среда);
}
```

Дополнительный метод:

```cs
static string JoinGroup(string name, IGrouping<object, DataRow> g)
{
    return string.Join(", ", g
        .Where(n => n.Field<bool>(name))
        .Select(n => n["время_начала"] + " - " + n["время_конца"]));
}
```